# Magento Absolute Positioning Home Screen CSS Settings

Tags: css, magento

Hello I am trying to put a few images that slightly overlap on the home page. I am using the following css settings that I found online:

```
#png1 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
padding-top:20px;
}

#png2 {
position:absolute;
/*
set top and left here
*/
z-index:2;
padding-left:275px;
top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}
#png3 {
position:absolute;
/*
set top and left here
*/
z-index:1;
padding-left:610px;
top:0px;
padding-top:20px;
}
```

The issue I have is that the first image #png1 is showing in the top left far corner.

The next two images are overlapping correctly put are also on the very top of the screen.

Comment: Where do you want the images in relation to each other? Can you spell that out more clearly?

Comment: I want the three images next to eachother the middle image overlaps on the left and right. The images are 305x350px each.... When I preview it in dreamweaver looks great. Its only when I put it in magento the first image is not right. The images are going behind the header nagivation bar. They should be staying in the center column (cms page).

Comment: Can you make an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It'll be much easier to help you that way. Or can you link to a screenshot of your Dreamweaver output?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positionning will position in the (ie. top left) corner of the first "relative" parent.

Be sure your main column is set to relative.

Then, try not to combine left and padding.

```
First : top: 0;left: 0;
Last : top:0; right:0;

Middle : top:0; left:XXXXpx (need to found this value according to your needs, looking at chosen paddings I must say 275px;)
```

Comment: That did work except for the last image. THe last image is going under the first image "next line"...